# use package from pip local instead pip global

Tags: python, pip, theano

I have Theano library installed on

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/
```

but the Theano installed is the old one and I am using some library that can't import some packages.

So I tried to install the new one using

```
pip install --user theano in ~/.local
```

but everytime I import theano, the version is the old one which come from

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/...
```

So I need to know how to make import theano load my `~/.local` theano, not the `/usr/local/lib` theano.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the old version wasn't installed with pip, but probably with easy_install. This cause many type of problems.

You can fix it by changing the import order after starting python. To do so, in your python script before importing theano do something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = ["THE_PYTHON_PATH_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD"]
```

THE_PYTHON_PATH_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD is something like `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`